# Using JFileChooser via socket so you can open choose where to save an object

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jfilechooser

I have established a connection between two computers, one is the server and the other one is the client. I am being able to save an object on the server computer but I´m wondering if there is a way to choose where to save it.
I'm familiar with JFileChooser and I got it to open on the server computer and there I could choose where to save it but that's not practical. 
Is there a way to implement JFileChooser or something else to make it possible to choose the saving spot from the client computer?

Comment: You can extend the FileSystemView class with a class that delegates all method calls through a socket to a proxy running on the server. Could be a fun exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My teacher said it is not necessary for this project but I have the feeling that I will someday try it!